# Why is the following text getting the error "! Undefined control sequence."?

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\normalsize 
\section{The Model}

${\P}\_t$ is a stochastic process representing the stock price. 
${\varphi}\_t$ is the borrowing cost of 1 share on the time interval [t, t+dt]. 
It is assumed the interest rate is 0.
$\X_{t}^{Q}$ = Capital of squeezer.


\end{document}
```

I believe the error is coming from the notation used for the capital of the squeezer but cannot find out what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is `\P` defined?

Comment: @Bernard Well, `\P` is actually a kernel macro, the undefined one is `\X`.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by defined and undefined. Apologies, I am a beginner with TeX.

Comment: @KillianGavin Undefined means that the macro `\X` *does not exists*. Therefore your attempt to use it does not work.

Comment: You need to define `\X`. For example in document preamble add `\newcommand\X{\mathbf{X}}` if X had to be in boldface. But I gues that you looking for just `P` and `X` .

Comment: At first glance, I though he meant the Greek letters, where he mistyped `Pi` as `P` and `Xi` as `X` since there was already one Greek letter that was correctly typed.

Comment: Please do tell what `\P` and `\X` are supposed to a accomplish or look like.

Answer (score 1):

I know very little about stochastic process notation other than what I gleaned from looking at a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process) just now. From that, I think that you actually meant to write:

```
$\{P_t\}$ % ❶
is a stochastic process representing the stock price. 
$\{\varphi_t\}$ % ❷
is the borrowing cost of 1 share on the time interval 
$[t, t+dt]$. % ❸ 
It is assumed the interest rate is 0.
$X_{t}^{Q} = \mbox{Capital of squeezer}$. % ❹
```

❶ I assumed that you want printed curly braces with the subscript inside per the notation described at the wikipedia article. I also got rid of the `\` because I'm pretty sure you wanted to print *P* and not ¶. By the way `%` indicates a comment and the black numbers are my way of enabling references to commentary in the midst of the code. I always preceded these notes with a `%` so that copy-and-pasters won't get errors from their appearance.

❷ Similar modification to the appearance, although this is more of a financial notation .

❸ *all* mathematical material should be inside `$`…`$`, not just the stuff that LaTeX gives you an error for. You'll find that this change gives better spacing and also prints *t* and *dt* in math italics which is what you would want.

❹ I got rid of the `\` before `X` since `\X` doesn't mean anything. I also moved the phrase “Capital of squeezer“ inside the mathematics since it's the right hand side of the `=` and thus part of a mathematical expression. This, in turn, is enclosed inside `\mbox` so that it will be treated as text.¹

---

1. An even better approach is to use the `\text` command from the `amsmath` package instead of `\mbox`, but that adds a level of complexity to the answer that isn't necessary at this point, so this footnote is mostly for the other commenters.

Comment: An even better practice than `\text` is `\textup`, which won't suddenly change to italic if the expression happens to occur in the middle of a theorem or other text environment that's normally italic.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The gotcha here is that `\text` will change size with context but `\textup` gives the same results as `\mbox`. Writing a book on LaTeX gets one exploring a lot of edge cases.

Comment: If `\textup` doesn't do the right thing in context, then `\mathrm` would.  But I'd be inclined to report misbehaving `\textup` as a bug.  In any event `\mbox` is not the best answer here.

Comment: `\mathrm` won't preserve spaces. I had to do some digging in my buddy `source2e.pdf` (I kind of want to keep a monitor on my desktop dedicated to showing just that), to discover that the size changing from `\textup` is dependent on having `amsmath` loaded. Otherwise, the `\textXX` commands are equivalent to using `\mbox`. This conversation has just dramatically improved lesson 7-7 of the book. The thing that should be updated, more than anything else, is `amsldoc.pdf` which could be better written (and fails to acknowledge that `\textrm` works with and without `amsmath` just without the

Comment: size changing feature.